Why does Chrome downloads tab no longer adhere to the Chrome.downloads API?
I am trying to download a very large file using Selenium ChromeDriver. Downloading it directly through Selenium does not work since the file is much too large. Instead, I have Selenium initiate the download, then switch over to the chrome://downloads/ tab to watch until the download finishes. Afterwards, I can SSH into the remote server and grab the file that way.
I looked at the downloads-manager element on the chrome://downloads/ tab using the following commands in the console.
document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList').items[0]

Or
document.querySelector('downloads-manager').__data.items_[0]

The result used to follow the Chrome.downloads API documentation. dangerType, and state would match one of the possible strings listed. Now though, on Chrome version 125.0.6422.61, the dangerType and state variables are simply obscure integers, instead of strings like they used to be.
Is this change documented anywhere? Am I accessing the list of download items incorrectly?
